# Chrome clears localStorage on closing browser/ error in my code/ I do not understand something totally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I work over a small React app that should store some data in local storage. And if I understand it correctly, it should keep them till clearly ordered to clear. The reason for this post is that while app data perfectly survives the refreshing page action, it disappears after closing/opening Chrome.

Here is the function which creates the storage:

```
export function initGlobalStorage() {

    var Storage = function (options) {
      options = options || {};
      for (var i in options) {
        this[i] = options[i];
      }
    };
    const prefix = window.location.href;

    Storage.prototype = {
      storage: window.localStorage,
      addPrefix: function(key){return (prefix + key); },
      
      set: function (key, value) {
        this.storage.setItem(this.addPrefix(key), JSON.stringify(value));
      },
      get: function (key) {
        return this.storage.getItem(this.addPrefix(key));
      },
      remove: function (key, value) {
        this.storage.remove(key, value);
      },
      clear: function () {
        this.storage.clear();
      },
      key: function (index) {
        return this.storage.key(index);
      },
      each: function (fn) {
        if (typeof fn === "function") {
          for (var i = 0, key; i < this.storage.length; ++i) {
            key = this.storage.key(i);
            fn(this.storage.getItem(key), key, i);
          }
        }
      },
      getAll:function(){
        let result =[];
        for(var key in this.storage){
          if (key.includes(prefix)){result.push(JSON.parse(this.storage.getItem(key)))};
        }
        return result;
      },
      hasItems:function(){
        console.log(this.getAll().length);
        return this.getAll().length? true:false;
      },
    };
  

window.Storage = {
    local: new Storage({ storage: window.localStorage }),
    session: new Storage({ storage: window.sessionStorage }),
  };
};
```

window.local.href is for distinguish 'my items' in localStorage from others that possibly exists there on client computer. BTW, currently I only test this app on localhost.
Here is how above function is applied

```
export function checkSupportForCache() {
  return dispatch => {
    if (storageAvailable('localStorage')) {
      dispatch(cacheSupported());
      console.warn("Storage available");
      initGlobalStorage();
      if (window.Storage.local.hasItems()){
        console.log('Storage contains items');
        dispatch(cacheNotEmpty());  
      }else{
        console.warn("No items in storage");
      }
      

    } else {
      console.warn("Storage not available");
    }
  };
}
```

`storageAvailable('localStorage')` is a function that checks support for localStorage in a certain browser.
As I have written, when I refresh page localStorage is still there - then I suppose code is OK.
But what happens when do close browser then? I do not consciously request for any sort of purging action. Do I unconsciously? I have checked Chrome settings and there is nothing that looks suspicious. Do I not understand anything at all as per subject? Maybe, just give me a hint.

Comment: _"it disappears after closing/opening Chrome"_ - Then it's a "problem" with Chrome (`chrome://settings/content/cookies` -> _"Keep local data only until you quit your browser"_) which you could easily verify with another browser.

Comment: Chrome doesn't clear local storage, so something in your code is doing so. If I take your `Storage` code and put it in a page, I don't get the problem you describe. Please update the question with a [mcve] one can copy and paste to see the problem happen. (Sadly, you can't use Stack Snippets for this, they disallow local storage.) However, I do strongly recommend that you **don't** overwrite the [built-in `Storage` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) with your own (don't do `window.Storage = ...`).

Comment: You don't need to prefix your items in the local storage. The browser won't let you access anybody else's data anyways. And actually it might be the prefix that causes the issue, try without it.

Comment: Andreas answer was correct and the simplest / the simplest and correct. I do not know how, but i omitted that Chrome option. Thanks for all for support